# In TypeScript, why an exclamation mark on a class field?

Tags: typescript

In TypeScript, what is the purpose of an exclamation mark on the class field property?

```typescript
class MyDataApiResponse {
    name!: string
    age!: number
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The exclamation on a class field is called the [*definite assignment assertion operator*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#fields). It tells the TypeScript compiler not to generate this error:

> error TS2564: Property has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.

To see that error, remove the exclamation marks from the field and compile with the `--strict` option.

It is useful if you know that the fields will be initialized by something other than a constructor. (For example, by JSON deserialization.)